# Passing an object reference to a function

Tags: php, class

I am tryingto pass the reference of a object to a php function , can anyone show me an example. I did look on google, for about an hour but could not find completely what I was looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious - could you please show us your google searches that didn't help?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference by default in PHP5+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are always passed by reference in PHP:

```
$a = new Class();
$b = new OtherClass();
$a->setB($b);
```

This will pass `$b` as reference to `$a->setB()`